# Set different ease-in and ease-out values for a single transition without affecting the other transitions using CSS?

Tags: css

Really simple. I just want to do this:

```
.div
{
    padding-top: 16px;
    transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out, filter 1000ms ease-in 250ms ease-out;
}
.div:hover
{
    transform: translateY(-16px);
    filter: brightness(110%) drop-shadow(0px 16px 16px red);
}
```

I only want to make the `filter` **ease-in** *slower*, yet **ease-out** with the `transform` at the *same* time.

It's all correct CSS till this part `filter 1000ms ease-in 250ms ease-out;` which is just an illustration code to what I wished I could do.

I also tried

```
transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out, filter 1000ms ease-in, filter 250ms ease-out;
```

But setting the `filter` more than 1 time just overrides the previous one.
Is there a CSS-only solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

**Yes**, there is.

Since currently CSS does not support setting both `ease-in` and `ease-out` individually for a transition **without affecting other transitions**, you'll have to use a "hack" which is to use the `:not(:hover)` event to set the filter's `ease-out`.

```
.div:not(:hover)
{
    transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out, filter 250ms ease-out;
}
```

Now every time you stop hovering, the **`filter`** is overridden resetting the `ease-in` property to default while simultaneously setting `ease-out` to whatever duration wanted giving the effect precisely described.

The `ease-in` is actually ignored inside `:not(:hover)` so it doesn't matter if it is a default value or infinity. Knowing the previous, you could set both of `ease-in-out` inside `:not(:hover)` if you want and it'd make 0 difference.

**Full code**:

```
.div
{
    transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out, filter 1000ms ease-in;
}
.div:hover
{
    transform: translateY(-16px);
    filter: brightness(110%) drop-shadow(0px 16px 16px red);
}
.div:not(:hover)
{
    transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out, filter 250ms ease-out;
}
```

Note that not only the filter's `ease-out` is overridden, but the **entire** `transition` which is why you have to set all other transitions in it again even though you changed only one.

This solution is **not only for hovering** as it could be replicated with other events. It is but a matter of changing `:hover` in the code above to whatever event you seek.